# Hyphens on Safari: "Unsupported Property Name"

Tags: css, safari, css-hyphens

From reading around this topic, I've realised that there are a lot of problems with hyphens on Safari. I couldn't find a mention of this one however.

I've designed a website with the following CSS rules:

```
body {hyphens: none}

@media screen and (max-width: 342px) {
    h1, h2 {
        word-break: break-word;
        hyphens: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

Most of the time, I don't want hyphens, the exception being for larger titles on very small screens.

This works well on Firefox and Chrome. On Safari however, the `hyphens` rule is accompanied by a yellow triangle warning symbol and greyed out with the message "unsupported property name". This is weird because `hyphens` is [apparently supported by Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens). Hyphens then seem to be applied on all screen sizes anyway.

You can view the issue on Safari with the first title on [this page](https://drthivi.com), where it says "Maruthappu". I also have some screenshots below.

[image: Image showing incorrect application of hyphens on Safari]

[image: Image showing warning message from Safari "unsupported property name"]

Comment: It seems that on Chrome, the word "MARUTHAPPU" is never broken. So you might fix it for safari by setting `word-break` to `keep-all` only for that title?

Comment: _"This is weird because hyphens is apparently supported by Safari."_ - notice that `-x-` icon there below Safari? And how there is a legend under that table, _"`-x-` - Requires a vendor prefix or different name for use"_ ...? And if you click on the Safari cell, it will even tell you which prefix.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much for your comment, this fixed the issue. Didn't spot the -x- there!